Bank statement query for visa applications
My bank doesnt print my full name as per my passport on the statement.  I remember using the same for uk visa and it didnt create an issue .but can i submit an certificate(it will have my bank account full name and other details saying i have a valid account in the bank) from the bank also with the statement for any other country like schengen or usa or Canada? Or if full names are not printed will it be acceptable?

Is this only a middle name that's missing, like "John Edward Doe" being listed as "John Doe"? This is extremely common, at least in Europe, and shouldn't be an issue. Or is it something more complicated?

See this question with regards to problems with submitting a certificate of balance alone. If the certificate has your full personal details, and the statement has the full listing of transactions - it would probably be best to submit them both and show how they tie together (same bank account number on both, for example).

Yes the bank certificate has my full name, account number and swift codes
